# How to update second screen of tic tac toe game using firebase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a 2 player online Tic Tac Toe game using Firebase. I am stuck at the point where I am unable to update player 2 screen with player 1's moves. I have tried to test this in two separate tabs and when i click on a square in the grid with eg. X it does not show on the second tab which is player two. I am attaching screenshots of my code of the function which writes to firebase, reads on change, and processes the read on change. The processreadonChange() function is where I am trying to update the second screen using an array. Please have a look and advise, as I have been trying to figure this out but have not been unable to. I have attached all the necessary functions snipets below. Thanks

```js
function fb_readOnChange(_path, _key, _data, passFunc) {
  console.log('fb_ReadOnChange: ' + _path + '/' + _key);

  readStatus = 'waiting...';
  var ref = database.ref(_path + '/' + _key);
  ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

  function gotData(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.val() != null) {
      var dbData = snapshot.val();

      passFunc('OK', snapshot.key, dbData, _data);

      //display to screen 
      //if (userScores.highScore > hitsCntr) {
      //document.getElementById("highscore_counter").innerHTML = //userScores.highScore;
      //}

    } else {
      console.log("db_ReadOnChange: No rec for" + _path + '/' + _key);
      passFunc("n/a");
    }
  }

  function errData(err) {
    console.log(err);
    readStatus = 'error';
  }
} //end of db_read()
```

```js
function fb_processReadOnChange(_result, _key, _dbData, _data) {
  console.log("fb_processReadOnChange: result = " + _result + 
              " key = " + _key + "\nmarker = " + marker + 
              " getId = " + PLAYER[playernum].getId + 
              " getValue = " + PLAYER[playernum].getValue);
  console.table(_dbData);//DIAG
  if (_result == 'n/a') {
  } else { 
    console.log(_dbData);
    if (marker == 1){ // marker 1 means some box has been clicked else undefined 
     
     document.getElementById(PLAYER[playernum].getId).value = PLAYER[playernum].getValue;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
function readonCreate() {
  playernum = 0;
  symbol = 'X';
  console.log("readonCreate userDetails.uid = " + userDetails.uid);
  db_write(GAMEDATA, userDetails.uid, gameData);
  //fb_readOnChange(GAMEDATA, userDetails.uid, gameData.active, fb_processReadOnChange);
  fb_readOnChange(GAMEDATA, userDetails.uid, gameData.p2Move, fb_processReadOnChange);
}

function readonJoin() {
  playernum = 1;
  symbol = '0';
  console.log("readonJoin userDetails.uid = " + userDetails.uid);
  db_writeUpdate(GAMEDATA, userDetails.uid, gameData);
  fb_readOnChange(GAMEDATA, userDetails.uid, gameData.p1Move, fb_processReadOnChange);
}
```

```js
const PLAYER = [{
getValue: 'X',
getId: ''
},
{
getValue:'0',
getId: ''
}];
```

```js
function ttt_onclick(_id) { // Functions checks turn of the player
                            // and put accordingly value X or 0
                            //Then writes player moves to firebase
                                                     
var elem = document.getElementById('b'+_id);
PLAYER[playernum].getId = 'b'+_id;
//PLAYER[playernum+1].getId = 'b'+_id; 
//getId = 'b'+_id;

console.log(elem)
//if (flag == 1) {
  if (symbol == "X") {
        elem.value = "X";
    getValue = "X";
        elem.disabled = true;
        flag = 0;
    marker = 1;    
    }
    else {
        elem.value = "0";
    getValue = "0";
        elem.disabled = true;
        flag = 1;  
    marker = 1;
    }

if (elem.textContext != "") {
  if (elem.value=="X"){
    gameData.p1Move = 'b'+_id;
    console.log(gameData.p1Move);
  } else {
    gameData.p2Move = 'b'+_id;
    console.log(gameData.p2Move);
  }
db_writeUpdate(GAMEDATA, userDetails.uid, gameData);
//console.log(gameData);
}
}
```